# return a remote image from php

Tags: php, html

I have a database that sometimes returns a blob as an image and sometimes needs to fetch an image, when its a blob - I simply

```
$imageInfo = getimagesize($row['dealImage']);
switch ($imageInfo[2]) {
    case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
        header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
        break;
    case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
        header("Content-Type: image/gif");
        break;
    case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
        header("Content-Type: image/png");
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

    if(base64_decode($row['dealImage']) == false)
        echo $row['dealImage'];
    else
        echo base64_decode($row['dealImage']);
```

In my other case I get the URL from

```
$from['dealpromoimageURL']
```

But I need to return it the same was as above

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: What is the issue you are having? BTW it's best to store images as files not blobs and just store the location of it in the DB.

Comment: $from['dealpromoimageURL'] is returning the URL, not the bytes...

Comment: In case of url just echo it in image tag - <img src="$from['dealpromoimageURL'] " ?>